# Databinding in Android cannot find a setter with java.langString

Tags: android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding

I am doing databinding with a custom component and I am running into difficulties trying to bind a string to value in my xml.

Here is the xml component in the xml. The issue was with the progressText string replace of dynamic variables.  I am getting a

> Cannot find a setter for <com.mycompany.CircleProgressBar
>   cpb:progressText> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'

error when trying to compile the xml.

```
            <com.mycompany.CircleProgressBar
                xmlns:cpb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/progressWheel"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                cpb:progress="@{viewmodel.progress}"
                cpb:progressColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                cpb:backgroundColor="@color/gray"
                cpb:backgroundWidth="10"
                cpb:textSize="10sp"
                cpb:differenceInTextSizeInLines="10"
                cpb:roundedCorners="true"
                cpb:progressText="@{@string/work_package_percent_complete(viewmodel.progress)}"
                cpb:spaceBetweenLines="5"
                cpb:maxValue="100"
                cpb:progressTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Here is how I declare the variable used in my CircleProgressBar:

```
@BindingAdapter("progressText")
fun setTextView(view: CircleProgressBar, value: String) {
    if (this::ta.isInitialized) {
        this.text = ta.getString(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_progressText) as String
    } else {
        this.text = value
    }
    view.invalidate()
}
```

When I try to do an import statement for String at the top of my xml file, I am getting a duplicate that String is is already declared.  If I just put in straight text without the string replacement, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `BindingAdapter` is often abused, because it's overkill for simple bindings. The idea is to have these generated, not to program them - and a `String` getter/setter with the expected name is enough for that. In order to expose the expected methods, these methods just need to be called:

- `setProgressText(value: String)`
- `getProgressText()`

When the `CircleProgressBar` is a field, it doesn't have to be passed into the method, preserving the expected method signature, about which's absence it explicitly complains. It doesn't even have to be a field in the view-model, because the model should not depend on views.